# Проверить есть ли несколько элементов в листе1 из листа2

Tags: c#

Есть 2 листа.
В первом листе есть:

```
dll|51326
ogg|8921
png|123
ott|896236
```

Во втором листе есть:

```
dll|6526
png|123
ott|896236
```

Первый лист неизменный.
Нужно сделать наверное цикл, который который будет добавлять в другой(третий лист) недостающие или неправильный элементы второго листа, которые есть в первом листе. То есть сейчас во втором листе элемент dll неправильный(число), элемента ogg вообще нет, а элементы png и ott - есть и они правильные(числа правильные). Мне нужно чтобы неправильные или недостающие элементы(в данном случае dll и ogg) добавились в 3 лист.
Я знаю что у листа есть свойство Contains, но как его здесь применить - не знаю. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: К чему все эти пояснения без кода? Если у вас сть 2 списка - покажите их код. Вы вводите какие то понятия типа "правильный элемент" и "неправильный элемент" - но эти понятия только у вас в голове существуют, нам вы об этом ничего не сказали. Далее, то у вас элементы в списках, то числа, то два списка, то три. Без кода это просто бессмыслица. Вот как это для непосвещенных выглядит: `у меня есть два поля, одно Вася, второе 42, как сделать хорошо, чтобы третий класс работал?`

Comment: `var result = list1.Except(list2);`, только не забудьте переопределить у класса `Equals` и `GetHashCode`, благо студия умеет это сейчас делать в 1 клик.